# Using jQuery .after inside loop

Tags: loop, jquery, ajax, javascript, content

I have a bit of javascript that will dynamically add a static post to a loop. The script uses the jQuery 'after' method and on a static page it works beautifully but when inside the loop I don't get any results.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here? Does WP not allow DOM insertion within a loop?

```
function newTile(){
  var adTile = "<div class='new-box' id='article-tile'><h1> this is a test</h1>    </div>";
  var adLoc = 5;
  var tiles = $('#article-tile:nth-child('+adLoc+')');
  $(tiles).after(adTile);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `tiles` contains a DOM element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WordPress requires **no-conflict** for jQuery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers).

Change this:

```
var tiles = $('#article-tile:nth-child('+adLoc+')');
$(tiles).after(adTile);
```

...to this:

```
var tiles = jQuery('#article-tile:nth-child('+adLoc+')');
jQuery(tiles).after(adTile);
```

Or else wrap your entire script accordingly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

Comment: Or even `(function($){})(jQuery);` would work ^_^